# Changes to $_SESSION without page reload

Tags: php, ajax, session, session-variables

I have two `$_SESSION` variables declared as array in `index.php`, say:

```
$_SESSION['a'] = array(1,2,3);
$_SESSION['b'] = array(4,5,6);
```

I make a AJAX call from `index.php` to `result.php`, where values of session variables are changed
to, say:

```
$_SESSION['a'] = array(2,3,1,4);
$_SESSION['b'] = array(5,6);
```

What I do is, I remove the first element from both the arrays and append it back to first array, `$_SESSION['a']`.

On successful AJAX call, I want to print the first elements of both the variables in `index.php`. Is it possible?

Comment: Just deliver them back on the AJAZ call. Then do what you like with them in JS...

Comment: Any particular reason why you roll backed my edit?

Comment: I didn't realize, I was trying to put my question straight. Sorry!
I'm still stuck, can you please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, on a successful ajax call, you can do that.

Comment: Well, I assume you can code ... in that case, you can return ajax response with the new values of `true` or `false` and make the script read the `$_SESSION` value again.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward.

In your `results.php` you simply returned the new data with a bit of JSON.

result.php:

```
//set the session vars to whatever here....

//now, return them. In the example, I shall assign your session vars to temp vars.

$sessA=$_SESSION['a'];
$sessb=$_SESSION['b'];

echo json_encode(array('a'=>$sessA,'b'=>$sessb));
```

And now in your AJAX (assuming you're using jQuery):

```
$.getJSON('results.php', function(data){

alert(data.a);
alert(data.b);

});
```

And there you have it.

EDIT:

In your index.php, you say you set the session vars to the original value. But in your comments, you say you want to use the new vars in index.php. This won't be possible if you are setting them to the original value in index.php on every request. What you should do is check if they're already set first, and then do what needs to be done. Like this:

instead of:

```
$_SESSION['a'] = array(1,2,3);
$_SESSION['b'] = array(4,5,6);
```

Do this:

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['a']) === false && isset($_SESSION['b']) === false )
{

# - The vars are not already set...so it's okay to set them to its original value.

$_SESSION['a'] = array(1,2,3);
$_SESSION['b'] = array(4,5,6);

}
```

Comment: I print, $_SESSION['a'][0] and $_SESSION['b'][0] in index.php. But for some reason, it prints the first element according to old array and not the newly set array!

Comment: are you sure you called `session_start()` properly in result.php?

Comment: You must reload the page after your AJAX request if you want to use the new session vars in the PHP source of index.php. Also, as you say in your question, you set the session vars on `index.php`, which could mean you're re-writing them every time you load index.php to the old value. To prevent this, check my up coming edit.